# microservices and bounded contexts

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, consistency

For the sake of question, let's say i have 2 microservices.

- Identity management
- Accounting

I know that each microservice should not be tightly coupled and it should have it's own database.

Let's say that accounting has invoices and each invoice has issuing agent. 
Agent from accounting also exists as User in Identity microservice.

If i understood well, data from identity management (users), should be copied to accounting (agents), and should copy only data which are needed for that bounded context (first and last name), so the invoice can have proper `issuingAgentId`.

Is this correct way to keep data consistent and shared between contexts?
Each time when user is created in identity microservice, event "UserCreated" will be published and accounting or any other service interested in this event should listen and process it by adding corresponding agent?
Same goes for updating user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to handle it yes and usually the preferred method. You keep a cache locally in your service that holds copies of the data from another service. In an event-driven system, this would involve listening to events of interest and using them to update your local cache. The cache could be in-memory, or persisted. An example for your use case would be when raising an invoice, the Accounting context would look in it's local cache for a user/agentid before creating the Invoice.

Other options:

**Shared database**

I know it is frowned upon (for good reason) but you can always share a database schema. For example, the Identity context can write to a user table and the Accounting context can read from it when it needs an AgentId to put in an invoice. The trade-off is you are coupling at the database level, and introducing a single point of failure.

**RPC**

You can make a RPC call to another service when you need information. In your example, the Accounting context would call the Identity Management context for the AgentId/User information before raising an invoice. Trade-off with this approach is again a coupling to the other service. What do you do when it is not available? You cannot raise an Invoice.

**Reporting domain**

Another option is to have a completely separate service that listens for data from other services and maintains view models for UIs. This would keep your other services ignorant of other service's concerns. When using an event-driven system, you'd be listening for events form other services that allow you to build a view model for the UI. This is usually a good option if all you are doing is viewing the data

Comment: why In-memory? When you say UI service, in my example that means that accounting service would only have AgentId, but it would ne UI service responsibility to construct first and last name from Agent Id?

Comment: Doesn't have to be in memory, can be persisted if needed. By having a separate service just for UI views you pass all responsibilities to it for aggregating data needed for any views. Just one option though :)

Comment: That is very good idea actually. I am just concerned how will invoice service know is AgentId valid if it does not have that data within its context and uses UI service for aggregation.

Comment: Well how would it know if the AgentId was valid if you copied the name details to the accounting service? This sounds like a different requirement. I'm not saying a separate service just for UIs is the right solution for you, it's just one option. It might be better to do as you suggest in your question as it is simpler

Comment: I would know cause event publisher is the microservice who has the right information about AgentId and data would be persisted in that  way in the subscribing MS, but the UI microservice sounds really well and adds more option to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @tomliversidge how does your second solution address the need for consistency inside the Accounting BC regarding, say, `AgentId` ? For instance, when creating an invoice, how can you guarantee that its AgentId is a valid one ?

Comment: No idea, don't know what the process of validating an AgentId is

Comment: By valid, I mean one that existed as a User in the Identity BC in the first place... Without that guarantee, you can find yourself with a deficient view model service where one half of the view model is nowhere to be found.

Comment: If a reporting service has subscribed to events to build a view how do you end up with half of it being missing? I don't understand how you'd get into this state, sorry

Comment: @guillaume31i think i understand what you are saying now and have updated the answer

Comment: Actually "own database" does not necessarily mean "own database Server":

* Private tables per Service (managed via explicit grants) in the same database server.
* Private Schema per Service in the same database server.

The important thing is that those tables/schemas are free of FK to other service's schemas. In a big refactoring project the private tables approach would actually be my first choice in the first iterations.

Comment: I would say that RPC is not exactly the right term here for the described concept. You are doing a proper service call using some transport but it is not necessary RPC. You indeed get some coupling to a service *contract*, not service itself, but such coupling is not evil per se. I would say that having a risk of "not raising an invoice" when the identity service is down is minimal since when the id service is down - nothing works to put it simple. In addition, each service can be made redundant and resilient. Data duplication is easy in theory but too often gets wrong and it is hard to fix.