# What does bounded context mean in Microservices World?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, microservices

I have been learning to implement Microservices but I could not understand the term "bounded context"?

I could understand that it is concept which arises out of Domain Driven Design. But I could not understand the technical implementation of it.

I have looked at below links:

1. [microservices and bounded contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858550/microservices-and-bounded-contexts)
2. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/microservice-domain-model

Comment: What part do you not understand (exactly)? Saying "the technical implementation" is **too broad**.

Comment: @Sam see my updated answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is the biggest zone/area/place where a term has a consistent meaning (it means the same thing for the business specialists and the developers). I intentionally avoided using the word "context". Ideally, a Bounded context is exactly a Domain from the real world.

When it comes to microservices, a microservice should not be larger than a Bounded context.

UPDATE

A `Bounded context` *should be* an independent domain, if the system is correctly designed; in reality, when things are not done correctly, a `Bounded context` is larger than a domain. In large enterprises, some developers create objects (models) that try to capture all the behavior related to some term. For example, `Product` in a Shop. This term is very broad. The `Product` from the online-shop and the `Product` from the inventory system are not one and the same thing, although they may seem that way. In this case, the online-shop should be bounded context and the inventory should be a different one.

**Implementation**

Each "product" should have a different class in each bounded context, for example. A bounded context can be *implemented* as (a better expression would be "can be seen as") a `namespace` or `package` in monoliths, or as a **microservice** in distributed systems.

Comment: Bounded Context *should be* an independent domain, if the system is correctly designed; in reality, when things are not done correctly, a bounded context is larger than a domain. In large enterprises, developers create objects (models) that tries to capture all behavior related to some term. For example, `Product` in a Shop. This term is very broad. The "product" from the online-shop and the "product" from the inventory system are not the same thing, although they may seem that way. In this case, online-shop should be bounded context and inventory should be a different one.

Comment: Each "product" should have a different class in each bounded context, for example. A bounded context can be implemented as a `namespace` or `package` in most programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

Bounded Context is an independent domain. Let's imagine it as a different department in a company. Something like separation of concerns. An independent context in which all the stakeholders (Business Analysts, Testers, Developers, Business Folks) have the same definition of terms used in the Bounded Context. You can then have a separate microservice corresponding to each Bounded Context. For Example: If you in Insurance Domain, then you can have bounded context like Customer, Quote, Policy etc. and can have a micro-service for each of them.